# How to sort a list of dates and sort another list into the same order? vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, sorting

apologies if the question is worded awkwardly, I really don't know a better way to explain what I need.

I have a list of dates and a list of activities that happened on those dates like so:

```
Datelist(0) = 06/01/2015   Activitylist(0) = Kayaking
Datelist(1) = 04/01/2015   Activitylist(1) = Rock Climbing
Datelist(2) = 01/01/2015   Activitylist(2) = Hiking
Datelist(3) = 05/01/2015   Activitylist(3) = Orienteering
```

so on 06/01/2015 Kayaking was the selected activity and so on.

What I want to know is is there a way to reorder both the lists, preferably without using a loop and increment, so that they are in chronological order with this being the end result:

```
Datelist(0) = 01/01/2015   Activitylist(0) = Hiking
Datelist(1) = 04/01/2015   Activitylist(1) = Rock Climbing
Datelist(2) = 05/01/2015   Activitylist(2) = Orienteering
Datelist(3) = 06/01/2015   Activitylist(3) = Kayaking
```

is there a way to do this in vb .net using visual express 2013? Thank you in advance -Tom

Comment: Instead of 2 lists/arrays, why not use a Class to sort the info together as one using `.Sort`?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell if what is shown is actually a `List(Of T)` or an array.  The listing seems seems more like a data display since it otherwise has syntax problems.  Arrays are assumed.

If the LastDate and Activity are closely related, it is  better to keep them together in a class rather than storing individual bits of data in their own container and dissociated from each other.  For that, a class:

```
Public Class Activity
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property LastDate As DateTime
    Public Property Rating As Integer

    Public Sub New(n As String, dt As DateTime)
        Name = n
        LastDate = dt
        Rating = 1          ' some default
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then a (real) List to store them:

```
actList = New List(Of Activity)

Dim act As Activity
act = New Activity("Kayaking", #4/1/2015#)
actList.Add(act)

' short form, no temp var:
actList.Add(New Activity("Cat Herding", #6/1/2015#))
actList.Add(New Activity("Rock Climbing", #1/1/2011#))
actList.Add(New Activity("Bicycling", #6/1/2014#))
```

Lists are much easier to manage than arrays because you do not have to resize them or know how big to make them in advance.  To sort the list by date, use the `OrderBy` extension :

```
actList = actList.OrderBy(Function(d) d.LastDate).ToList
' display result:
For Each a As Activity In actList
    Console.WriteLine("act: {0}  last date: {1}", a.Name, a.LastDate.ToShortDateString)
Next
```

Results:

> act: Rock Climbing  last date: 1/1/2011
>   act: Bicycling  last date: 6/1/2014
>   act: Kayaking  last date: 4/1/2015
>   act: Cat Herding  last date: 6/1/2015

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to combine the two lists into one; then you can sort by the dates:

```
Dim datelist = { #06/01/2015#, #04/01/2015#, #01/01/2015#, #05/01/2015# }
Dim activities = { "Kayaking", "Rock Climbing", "Hiking", "Orienteering" }

Dim combined = datelist.Zip(activities, Function (ActivityDate, Activity) New With {ActivityDate, Activity}).ToList()

combined.Sort(Function (a, b) a.ActivityDate.CompareTo(b.ActivityDate))
```